# Cannot uploads a file to SharePoint Server

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, sharepoint, file-upload

I have a server farm on CloudShare consisting of three servers: a SQL Server 2012 server, a SharePoint 2013 server, and an Active Directory 2012 server.

I am writing an app in Node.js that uploads a file from the client to SharePoint 2013 using the REST API with jQuery/JavaScript. Currently, I am able to log in using the AD server, yet I am unable to make any REST API calls to upload any files, as I receive a `401 Unauthorized` from the SharePoint server.

please help, thanks

Comment: There's too little detail here, you need to provide some code to show how you're making your HTTP Request to the SharePoint REST API.

Comment: I am following the msdn "msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn769086.aspx"; - cross domain example. and it return 401 on line return jQuery.ajax({ url: fileCollectionEndpoint, type: "POST", data: arrayBuffer, processData: false, headers: { "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose", "X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(), "content-length": arrayBuffer.byteLength } })